# How can I tell if my iPad is 32 or 64-bit?

Tags: ios, ipad

How can I tell if my iPad is 32 or 64-bit? I use iOS 9.3.5.

I don't want to have to look at the back of my iPad (the iPad is badly scratched, I can't read anything on it, e.g. I cannot read the model number). I also don't know anything about the iPad (e.g., I don't know which yet it was purchased). The only information I have access to is whatever the programs installed on the iOS are telling me.

Answer (score 5):

Any iPad Air or later or iPad mini 2 or later has 64 bit processors.

This basically means any iPad released on/after November 2013.

In terms of iOS devices generally (i.e. iPods, iPhones and iPads) any device with an Apple A7 or later chip will be 64-bit.

For iOS devices generally (as well as tvOS and watchOS devices), you can refer to [Blake's iOS Device Specifications Grid](http://blakespot.com/ios_device_specifications_grid.html) for an easy reference to determine this and other specs.

**Note:** I have no affiliation with Blake Patterson or blakespot.com.

---

**If you have no idea what device you have**

If you aren't sure what device you've got, then:

1. Go to Settings > General > About
2. Make a note of the Model
3. Now visit [EveryMac.com's lookup page](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/)
4. You'll see a field labelled as: *Enter Mac, iPod, iPhone or iPad Identifier*
5. Enter the Model number you obtained at Step 2
6. Click on the <kbd>Lookup</kbd> button
7. Now you'll get a summary of the device with a link to full details
8. Compare that info with my answer above, or click on the link to view full details. If viewing full details you'll find whether it's a 32-bit or 64-bit processor that powers your device.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know anything about the iPad (e.g., I don't know which yet it was purchased). The only information I have access to is whatever the programs installed on the iOS are telling me.

Comment: Ah, okay, I've just added more info to my answer that should help. :)